# How to do component test for my custom Vue button using cypress?

Tags: vue.js, testing, vue-component

When I tried to component test for my custom Button of Vue using Cypress, I faced some questions.

This is my custom button handclick,

```
const handleClick = () => {
  if(typeof props.action === 'string') {
    window.location.href = props.action;
  } else if(typeof props.action === 'function') {
    props.action();
  }
};
```

I want to verify 'if action is relative or absolute link, clicking will redirect the browser to that link, if action is a function, then that function will be called on click' in component test.
in my test.cy.js

```
 it('redirects to link when action is a string', () => {
    const action = 'http://www.google.com';
    
    cy.mount(AosButton, {
      props: {
        colour: 'tertiary',
        action: action,
      },
    });
  
    cy.get('.tertiary').trigger('click', { force: true });
    cy.window().its('location').should('eq', action);
  });
```

after run,Error
'CypressError: Timed out after waiting `60000ms` for your remote page to load.
Your page did not fire its `load` event within `60000ms`.
You can try increasing the `pageLoadTimeout` value in `cypress.config.ci.js` to wait longer.
Browsers will not fire the `load` event until all stylesheets and scripts are done downloading.
'

I tried to make a stub,

```
it('redirects to link when action is a string', () => {
    const action = 'http://www.google.com';
  
    cy.mount(AosButton, {
      props: {
        colour: 'tertiary',
        action: action,
      },
    });
  
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.stub(win.location, 'assign').as('assignStub');
    });
  
    cy.get('.tertiary').click();
  
    cy.get('@assignStub').should('be.calledOnceWith', action);
  });
```

after run, Error
'redirects to link when action is a string:
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: assign
'.

So, what should be the test scope for component test? Should I make a stub for just checking handleClick is invoked with correct props? Or I made something wrong in details?
Thank you for your help.